# Behavior of stderr and stdout differs

Tags: c++, stdout, ksh, stderr, tcsh

stdout and stderr gives different result when run through `tcsh` and `ksh`.
As per my understanding the behavior in `ksh` is correct while in tcsh it is not.
My aim was to understand the difference between `cout` and `cerr` and so i wrote a small c++ program :

```
    std::cout<<"this goes in standard output\n";
    std::cerr<<"This goes in error output\n";
```

and produced `out` as the executable out of it.

I made two shell scripts one for ksh and other for tcsh as below:

```
:~/CPP/TEST [124]$ cat test
#!/bin/tcsh

      out 2>>error.log

:~/CPP/TEST [125]$ cat test1
#!/usr/bin/ksh

out 2>>error.log

:~/CPP/TEST [129]$ ./test
This goes in error output            //WRONG
:~/CPP/TEST [130]$ cat error.log
this goes in standard output         //WRONG
:~/CPP/TEST [131]$ ./test1
this goes in standard output         //OK
:~/CPP/TEST [132]$ cat error.log
this goes in standard output
This goes in error output            //OK
```

Isn't the behavior of `stderr`, `stdout` supposed to be the same across shells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this `tcsh` manual page](http://www.kitebird.com/csh-tcsh-book/tcsh.txt) you need to use `>>&` to redirect the error output (as well as standard output)

That manual also states

> The shell cannot presently redirect diagnostic output without also
>   redirecting standard output, but `(command >> output-file) >& error-file`
>   is often an acceptable workaround.

To summarize, in `tcsh` there's really no way to redirect the error output only to a file.